# ORA-00904 invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle

I get ORA-00904 'c' invalid identifier error. What is wrong with this alias ?

```
select NO, count(JOINT_NO) as c
from JOINT
WHERE HOLDER = 'Y' AND JOINT.c > 1
GROUP BY NO;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to fetch those records having count > 1. So you can't use `Indentifier C` in the `WHERE` clause of the same query.

```
select NO, count(JOINT_NO) as c
from JOINT
WHERE HOLDER = 'Y'
GROUP BY NO
HAVING COUNT(JOINT_NO)>1;
```

Answer (score 2):

There exists no column `c` in table `JOINT`, resulting in the error message you are getting.

Change your query like this:

```
select NO, count(JOINT_NO) as c
from JOINT
WHERE HOLDER = 'Y'
GROUP BY NO
HAVING count(JOINT_NO) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subselect(subquery) in the FROM clause:

```
 select T1.NO,T1.c
    from
    (
      select NO, count(JOINT_NO) as c
      from JOINT
      WHERE HOLDER = 'Y' 
      GROUP BY NO
    ) as T1
    where T1.c > 1
```

also you can use **having** :

```
    select NO, count(JOINT_NO) as c
    from JOINT
    WHERE HOLDER = 'Y'
    GROUP BY NO
    HAVING COUNT(JOINT_NO)>1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. I'd like to encourage you to explain your answer (doesn't have to be a long explanation), so future readers will understand what is going on. I suggest you take a look at [answer]